# HTTP response - Cliente JS y Servidor con Socket Python

Tags: python, servidor, http

He implementado un servidor TCP mediante python y socket. Del lado del cliente tengo JS. 
Debido a que con JS no puedo utilizar Sockets (TCP o raw socket) debido a las limitaciones que me impone el navegador, he decido utilizar XMLHttpRequest.

La información la recibo bien en el servidor y con eso sería suficiente pero del lado cliente, el navegado informa mala respuesta HTTP.

POST http://192.168.0.247:10000/ net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

En el cliente para enviar información utlizo el método POST

```
 request.open("POST", url);
     var header="@:~/|$&!";
     var mensaje = titulo+";¬^"+fecha + ";¬^"+tipo_de_evento+";¬^"+publico+";¬^"+area+";¬^"+descripcion_evento;
     request.send(header+mensaje);
```

Parte del código del servidor:

```
def ejecucion_servidor ():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('192.168.0.247', 10000)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
    sock.bind(server_address)
    sock.listen(25)
    while True:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
        try:
            connection, client_address = sock.accept()
            print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address
            # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
            while True:
                data = connection.recv(4096)
                print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
                if data:
                    #sacamos el header que nos dice que el mensaje debe grabarse en la base de datos
                    if "@:~/|$&!" in data:
                        datos = ''
                        for i in range(data.find("@:~/|$&!")+8, len(data)):
                            datos+=data[i]
                        print("se recibio: "+datos)
                        procesar_datos(datos)
                    #con otro header vemos que el mensaje viene de la aplicacion android
                    if data.find(":%\|/$&%")>=0:
                        print("nothing")
                    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                    respuestaHTTP="200 OK"
                    connection.sendall(respuestaHTTP)
                    break

                else:
                    print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                    break

        finally:
            # Clean up the connection
            connection.close()
```

Podrían por favor, indicarme, ¿Cuál sería la respuesta correcta de POST?

He probado con:

```
respuestaHTTP="200 OK"

respuestaHTTP="OK"
```

y

```
respuestaHTTP="200"
```